# Exceptional handling in ASP.NET file handler

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am processing PDF/JPG/GIF files using HTTP Handler.

A popup receives a btnId in query string and detects the file extension then calls the handler with btnId and processes the request.

Files are physical stored on server with file names in DB. 
When there is an issue with the file like file not found or some error I want an alert to be displayed and opened window to be closed which is not working right now.

I know the reason and that is I am writing the alert into response which will eventually land in either object tag or Image tag.

Can some one please suggest how can this be achieved. Help will be appreciated. Thanks!!!

```
Public Class ViewHelpContent
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    'Method that dynamically decides based on file extension which file viewer to render
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim embed As String = String.Empty
        Dim count As Integer
        Dim fileName As String = String.Empty
        Dim extension As String = String.Empty

        Try
            If Not IsPostBack Then
                If Not Request.QueryString("btnId") Is Nothing Then
                    Dim btnId As String = Request.QueryString("btnId").ToString()

                    count = GetFileAttachedToButton(btnId, fileName)
                    extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName)

                    If extension.ToLower() = ".pdf" Then
                        embed = "<object id=""objPDFViewer"" data=""{0}{1}"" type=""application/pdf"">"
                        embed &= "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = ""{0}{1}&download=1"">here</a>"
                        embed &= " or there is no file available to be viewed."
                        embed &= "</object>"
                    ElseIf extension.ToLower() = ".jpeg" OrElse extension.ToLower() = ".jpg" OrElse extension.ToLower() = ".gif" Then
                        embed = "<img id=""objImgViewer"" src=""{0}{1}"" alt=""No file is available to be viewed."" />"
                    Else
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alert", "alert('No help content uploaded for this button.');", True)
                        Return
                    End If

                    helpContent.Text = String.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/ProcessHelpContent.ashx?btnId="), btnId)

                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ExceptionHandler.LogError(ex)
            JSHelper.ShowSystemError(Me)
        End Try
    End Sub 
End Class





Public Class ProcessHelpContent
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

    'Sub that processes the help request and generates the requested content based on button Id
    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        Dim btnId As String = String.Empty
        Dim fileName As String = String.Empty
        Dim contentType As String = String.Empty
        Dim outputDir As String = String.Empty

        Dim count As Integer
        Dim strPath As FileInfo = Nothing
        Dim extension As String = String.Empty

        Try
            If Not context.Request.QueryString("btnId") Is Nothing Then
                btnId = context.Request.QueryString("btnId").ToString()
                outputDir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HelpContentFilesFolder")

                count = GetFileAttachedToButton(btnId, fileName)

                strPath = New FileInfo(outputDir & fileName)

                If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName) Then
                    If File.Exists(strPath.FullName) Then
                        extension = Path.GetExtension(strPath.FullName)

                        If context.Request.QueryString("download") = "1" Then
                            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", Convert.ToString("attachment; filename=") & fileName)
                        End If 
                   context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

                        If extension.ToLower() = ".pdf" Then
                            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
                        ElseIf extension.ToLower() = ".jpg" OrElse extension.ToLower() = ".jpeg" Then
                            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
                        ElseIf extension.ToLower() = ".gif" Then
                            context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif"
                        End If

                        context.Response.TransmitFile(strPath.FullName)
                        context.Response.Flush()
                    Else
                        context.Response.Write("<script>alert('Uploaded help file is missing. Please re-upload or contact administrator.'); window.close();</script>")
                    End If
                Else
                    context.Response.Write("<script>alert('Uploaded help file is missing. Please re-upload or contact administrator.'); window.close();</script>")
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ExceptionHandler.LogError(ex)
            context.Response.Write("<script>alert('Uploaded help file is missing. Please re-upload or contact administrator.'); window.close();</script>")
        End Try
    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```